# Option button selection event in VBA, Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I created a set of option buttons on VBA, which when selected have to administer the corresponding event. Example: If OptionButton1 is selected, then a particular line of code corresponding to that button has to occur. I tried using the code below but it didn't work, what is the correct syntax?

```
      If o1.Value = True Then
      stmt1
      ElseIf o2.Value = True Then
      stmt2
      End If
```

Here o1 and o2 are two different option buttons.

Comment: "It didn't work" is not very informative. Try with F8 to spot the problem. Also, how are you running the code?

Comment: @CMArg Running the code on the press of a regular button in the form i created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following screencast can help you resolve your problem.

[image]

The most important thing with these kind of projects is that (1) the names are correct, (2) the code for the button is located on the form, and (3) the code for the other macros is in a module.

Note in the screencast that I adjusted the names for the option buttons. Since the code for the button is on the form, `Me` refers to the form and the VBE automatically detects all the available objects on the form. So, when I start typing with `Me.` I get automatically to see the two option buttons with the names `.01` and `.02`.

Also, note that `.Value` is not necessary as it is the default. So, adding it to the code or skipping it will not change anything (it will still work as is). Finally, there is no need to check for `True = True`. If the option button `.Value` is `True` then the `If` statement will evaluate it to `True`. So, once again you may decide to skip writing `= True` (like I did) or you can add it to the code. That's won't change a thing and it will work either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Change Event like this:

```
Private Sub Option_Button_1_Change()

    If Option_Button_1.value = True Then
            MsgBox "Option_Button_1 selected"
        Else
            MsgBox "Option_Button_2 selected"
    End If

End Sub
```